# removing an index and put that array into a key

Tags: php

I have following output from an API

```
[location] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => re
                    [address] => add1
                    [phone] => +
                    [email] => asdf@asdf.com
                )
          )
```

I am trying to achieve the output as below

```
[location] => Array
        (
           
                    [name] => re
                    [address] => add1
                    [phone] => +
                    [email] => asdf@asdf.com
                
          )
```

Comment: `$array['location'] = $array['location'][0]`

Comment: Great works. Didn't think this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `location` is first level key in array `$array`:

```
$array['location'] = $array['location'][0];
```